# How to compare texbox with datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

I just need to validate a texbox with the year yyyy with a datepicker dd-mm-yyyy. 
is there any way to do this using javascript?
Thanks

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? In what format does it give the date (dd/MM/yy)?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
     $("#your_datepicker").datepicker({
           onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var startDate = new Date(dateText);
              var selectedYear = startDate.getFullYear(); // selected year
              var textbox = document.getElementById("txtBox").value  //you might need to cut the string depending on how the user should enter the year in the textbox
              if(textbox === selectedYear{
                 // Do what you need to
              }
           }
     });
});
```

I hope I understood your question correctly, if not you should give me additional information..

Comment: I have a form with:--year: textbox (YYYY)  and --date: datepicker (DD/MM/YYYY)

I need to compare that the year is equal in both fields

Comment: Well, that's what I assumed

Comment: how can I call this jq function in a input texbox?

Comment: Search for jquery Call function ontextchange in textbox, you will find a lot of options here on so